# Insert Code into Header Only on Blog Posts

Tags: headers

Is there a way to put some code into the header but have it load only on blog posts?

Maybe a plugin or a piece of code that could help me accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In your `functions.php` file, add something like the following:

```
function my_post_header_function() {
   if( is_single() ) {
      // Your Code Goes Here
   }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'my_post_header_function' );
```

What this will do is execute this when `wp_head()` is fired. It will see if you're on a single post (NOTE: This will *not* work on pages or attachments) and if you are, it will execute the code you want to put.

Comment: You're welcome. If you could, please click on the check to mark it as the answer.

Answer (score -1):

You could create another header called header-blog.php

Then on your blogs template replace the

```
 <?php
    get_header();
?>
```

with

```
  <?php
if ( is_home() ) :
    get_header( 'blog' );
else
    get_header();
endif;
?>
```

I know is_home is slightly confusing but this is what wordpress looks for as a blog page

also see https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header

Comment: It's a little overkill to create a completely different `header.php` file for only inserting a few lines of extra code. Plus it adds some maintainability problems down the road.